# Executing Jquery function on individual divs of the same class using 'this' selector

Tags: jquery, class, html

I'm trying to make a simple overlay when hovering over an image, the function works perfectly but appears on all divs with the class. I want to the function to run on the div that is hovered not all divs that have the same class.

I'm using this simple function to apply the .css inline.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.attachment-home-sub-feature, .thumb-hover').hover(function() {
        $('.thumb-hover').css({
            'display': 'block'
        });
    }, function() {
        $('.thumb-hover').css({
            'display': 'none'
        });
    });
});​
```

The HTML :

```
<div class="sfp-img">
<div class="thumb-hover"><a class="thumb-hover-link" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"></a></div><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) the_post_thumbnail('home-sub-feature'); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this)`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.attachment-home-sub-feature, .thumb-hover').hover(function() {
        $(this).css({
            'display': 'block'
        });
    }, function() {
        $(this).css({
            'display': 'none'
        });
    });
});​
```

Check it out - http://jsfiddle.net/LtmCP/

**EDIT:**

After reading your comment I think there's another approach doing it.
In your CSS , instead of having just `thumb-hover`create 2 classes:

1.`thumb-regular`

2.`thumb-hover`

One of them will be with display block and the other one with display none.
In your jQuery , instead of using `css()` , use `addClass` and `removeClass`.
(but still use `this` as in the code above)

Comment: This wouldn't work because it just hides the image. I have the image which is .attachment-home-sub-feature and .thumb-hover is hidden but positioned over the image. When hovering the image .thumb-hover will display.

Comment: I think i got it. can you please edit your question and add your HTML code?

Comment: Consider adding the HTML from the `view source` of your page and not directly from your file. I edited my answer , helped?

Comment: Not sure why it didn't work the first time I tried it this way but got it working now. http://pastie.org/4580818